# web2py ajax how to send param?

Tags: web2py

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#in').onclick=function()
  {
    var a='abc';
    ajax('echo',[a],'result');
  };
</script>
```

How can i send a local param with the ajax function?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the [`ajax()` function documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/11#The-ajax-function), the second argument to the function is an array of input field names, not arbitrary values. It reads the values stored in the named input fields and sends those values via a POST request. If you want to pass arbitrary values, you can do so by appending them to the URL in a query string:

```
var a = 'abc'
ajax('echo?a=' + a, [], 'result');
```

In that case, the value of `a` will be available within the `echo()` function as `request.vars.a`.